# value always undefined when I set it in promise angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a function getData() in accountService.ts. I'm trying to get user data and user account data together in zip promise. Resolve works correctly and I get the correct data, but when I try to set these local variables to the  returned values, they are always undefined. I want to set them to use them in other functions.

```
getData(){
    zip(this.getUser(), this.getAccount()).toPromise().then(data =>{
        this.user = data.values[0];
        console.log(this.user);            
        this.account = data.values[1];
        resolve(data.values[0],data.values[1]);
     });         
}
```

I use Angular 8 with typescript.

Thanks

Comment: We are probably going to need more information. I see a `resolve` method, but it's not clear what it does there. Besides that, javascript is an async language, which means that code is only executed from up to down in the same context. Once you are using `Observables` or anything async, the code below the observable statement is executed before it. Which for instance can happen that you return a variable that has not been set yet, because it will be set later when the observable completes, but then the function has already returned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `getData()` seems to return no values. I would follow the below approach

```typescript
getData(){
    return zip(this.getUser(), this.getAccount()).pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.user = data.values[0];
        this.account = data.values[1];
      }),
      map(({user, account}) => ({user, account}))
    )       
}
```

Now we are returning an `Observable<{user: any, account: any}>`. In the component where this function is used we can access the values using `subscribe`

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
  this.accountService.getData().subscribe({
    next: data => {
      // access account using data.account and user using data.user
    }
  })
}
```